# What types of errors arise when converting consistency parse trees to dependency parse trees?

Tags: computational-linguistics, parsing

I wonder what types of errors arise when automatically converting consistency parse trees to dependency parse trees, and how frequent they are.

Answer (score 1):

In Hungarian:

*Simkó, Katalin Ilona, et al. "[An Empirical Evaluation of Automatic Conversion from Constituency to Dependency in Hungarian.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13208204466103146196&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Proceedings of COLING. 2014.*

> The errors made during [the automatic] conversion were categorized manually in 200 sentences
>   selected randomly from the short business news subcorpus of the Szeged Dependency Treebank, and the
>   most typical ones are listed in Table 1, Column *convError*.

[image]